# Fortify Potential Buffer Overflow in unistd read call

Tags: c++, fortify, unistd.h

Fortify is saying that there is a potential buffer overflow in the unistd.h read function call that I have. Note that fd is a class variable  Code as follows:

```
std::size_t xyz::somefunction(const std::size_t numBytes, void* const buffer) throw (std::runtime_error)
{
    if(fd < 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("invalid file descriptor");
    return read(fd,buffer,numBytes);
}
```

Fortify is reporting read() as the sink and taint flags as NUMBER,STREAM,NOT_NULL_TERMINATED.

I haven't been able to find anything on SO or Google that would give me any idea what is wrong or what would need to be changed with this.

My best guess is it's possible that numBytes could be > length of buffer (which is passed in as a char*)

Comment: The snippet is OK on it's value. There is no way of knowing if the buffer size is adequate as compared to numBuffer from the provided snippet.

Comment: Your guess is exactly right.  The code needs to include a bufferSize and verify that numBytes is not larger than that.